# Installing Python Package from Github Using PIP

Tags: python, github, pip

I've seen it documented that you can install a Github hosting Python package using pip via:

```
sudo pip install -e git+git://github.com/myuser/myproject.git#egg=myproject
```

However, this appears to install the package to the current working directory, which is almost never where is should be.

How do you instruct pip to install it into the standard Python package directory (e.g. on Ubuntu this is /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages)?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The -e flag tells pip to install it as "editable", i.e. keep the source around.  Drop the -e flag and it should do about what you expect.

```
sudo pip install git+git://github.com/myuser/myproject.git#egg=myproject
```

If that doesn't work try using https instead of git.

```
sudo pip install git+https://github.com/myuser/myproject.git#egg=myproject
```

Comment: This is one of the first things I tried. Unfortunately, it just gives me the error "IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: /tmp/git+git:/github.com/myuser/myproject.git#egg=myproject"

Comment: Can you run pip --version and tell me what it says?  Make sure that you check the version of pip that you'll actually be using (if you will be installing inside a virtualenv, then make sure to check the version included in the virtualenv).

Comment: pip 0.3.1 from /usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages (python 2.6)

Comment: Can you "sudo pip install --upgrade pip" for me?  I believe this was a pip bug, and has been fixed several versions ago.  For the record, I'm running pip 1.0.2 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)

Comment: Indeed, that was the problem. Upgrading pip fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: I'm getting `Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/...`. I'm using pip 7.2.

Answer (score 2):

For Python 3 make sure you have python3-pip installed (and of course git installed):

The syntax just changed to:

```
sudo pip3 install git+git://github.com/someuser/someproject.git
```