# I have installed the package from github but when importing module name not found

Tags: python, github, conda

I'm trying to use this [github repo](https://github.com/gmum/pykernels)!

but as soon as I import the package: `from pykernels.basic import RBF`
the following error is displayed:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'basic'
```

I have double checked everything given my understanding of python, packages and how anaconda works but I don't know very much. The site-packages are in the path, the evn has the package and the init seems to be alright. I am really lost, if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong or what else might be done to resolve this? Thank you!

for installation:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/gmum/pykernels#egg=pykernels
```

Comment: use `python -m pip install git+https://github.com/gmum/pykernels#egg=pykernels`

Comment: @prashantrana I already tried that. no success :(

Comment: that repository is wriiten in python 2.7 and has no support for python3

Comment: try this repo [new repo](https://github.com/sahasrara62/pykernels)

Comment: see setup.py mentioned there , also syntax is written in python 2.7 , so if you want to run your project use python 2.7  , i removed that error

Comment: @prashantrana perfect!!! I feel i little dumb thanks a lot!!!

Comment: don't feel so, you learnt something, so you are not dumb anymore :D

Comment: @sahasrara62 Is there any way to make it working for python3?

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica this may [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9402035/installing-python-package-from-github-using-pip) or either download the repo and inside directory run command `python setup.py install`

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed both anaconda and original python, you will have two `pip` installed in your computer. The original python will have it's `pip` in `\Python37\Scripts`, and anaconda will have it's in `\Users\admin\Anaconda3\Scripts`. Your problem is that you used `pip` that is in `\Python37\Scripts`, the original pip. The original pip will install into the original python `site-packages`, not Anaconda's `site-packages`.

The solution is to make sure you're using Anaconda's `pip` when installing packages for use with Anaconda.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. How do you make sure you're using Anaconda's pip?

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica use `which pip` and see if the path refers to your conda environment folder.